# How to add conditional fields programmatically to a wagtail page type?

Tags: django, wagtail

I’m trying to add a conditional field to a wagtail page type model, the conditional fields may look like as shown in the below image. There are two fields, *Question* and *Answer*. The *Answer* field values should be displayed with respect to the selection of the *Question* field

[image]

If we select *Toyota* from Question then *Camry* and *Land Cruiser* should be displayed in the Answer drop down, if we select *Honda* then *Civic* and *Accord* should be displayed in the Answer.

In blocks.py I have two classes which are responsible for *Questions* and *Answers* fields respectively

```
class ConditionsQuestionBlock(blocks.ChooserBlock):
  widget = Select
  class Meta:
    icon = "question"

  @cached_property
  def target_model(self):
    return Question

  @cached_property
  def field(self):
    return forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Question.objects.all(),
        widget=self.widget,
        required=self._required,
    )

  def value_for_form(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, User):
        return value.pk
    else:
        print("selected q:",value)
        selectedqval=value
        print("selected qvalue:",selectedqval)
        return value

class ConditionsAnswerBlock(blocks.ChooserBlock):
  widget = Select
  class Meta:
    icon = "question"

  @cached_property
  def target_model(self):
    return Choice

  @cached_property
  def field(self):
    choice=Choice.objects.all()
    return forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=choice,
        widget=self.widget,
        required=self._required,
    )

  def value_for_form(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, User):
        return value.pk
    else:
        return value
```

Now irrespective of the *Question* selection I'm getting all the *Answer* options

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding, this is not achievable with `wagtail` or `Django` directly. This is actually a HTML question.

Wagtail and Django use pure HTML/CSS to create its UI elements. These UI elements interact with `python` code in wagtail/django using `HTML` forms submissions. That means using `POST` request.

Another way to interact with the `python` code is using redirections, meaning `GET` requests. But that way you can't access UI elements.

First you can have hidden choice fields for each answer group. In this case two choice fields, having *Camry* and *Land Cruiser* in one and *Civic* and *Accord* in the other one.

Then you have to write some `javascript` code to show/hide and required choice field when the question select event triggered. You can search for event triggers in `HTML` for more information.

After form is submitted, you can read the value of the question and the value of the corresponding answer field.